# Free an object if having only a pointer to it

Tags: delphi, variables, pointers, delphi-xe2

I have an array that stores pointers to some objects and I want to know if it's possible to free an object if you have only a pointer to it.
For example:

```
var test_form :Tform;
    p: Pointer;
vartest := Tform.create(nil);
p:=@vartest;
```

and if at runtime I only have **p**  is it possible to free **vartest**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pointer `p` points to a `TObject` variable. That is, `p` is a pointer to a reference to an object. Therefore you need to de-reference `p`. Like this: `p^`. Because `p` is un-typed you need to cast it before calling the Free method.

So, putting this together, you can free the object like this:

```
TObject(p^).Free;
```

This will not modify the `vartest` variable though. It will merely destroy the object. If you want to set `vartest` to `nil` as well then you can do it like this:

```
FreeAndNil(p^);
```

`FreeAndNil` is an odd beast because it takes an un-typed parameter. That's why you don't need to cast to `TObject`.

To avoid all this casting it would be preferable to declare p as a typed pointer, e.g. `^TObject` or `^TForm`.

Comment: thank you... i have just discovered myself just a moment ago :)

Comment: does it ? for what i see, p point to vartest, which is pointer itself.
aslong as vartest would go out of scope, p would become stray.

Comment: @Arioch'The That's right. We have to assume that `vartest` remains in scope. For example a global variable. Or a field in an object. The code in the question does seem a little, er, non-standard. Without knowing more context it's hard to say more.

Comment: that's why oppose to "p point to the object" statement.
vartest is NOT an object. That is the reason we require the .Free call at all. P is not the pointer to object - it does not warrant we can always free object by it. I think that is important not to hide those details, potentially pushing topicstarter to heisenbugs

Comment: @Arioch'The I honestly cannot understand that last comment. I realise that my first sentence was badly phrased (now updated). `p` is a pointer to an object reference.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to specify the type of the pointer, writing `p: ^TObject` instead of `p: pointer`, as such:

```
var test_form :Tform;
    p: ^TObject;

vartest := Tform.create(nil);
p:=@vartest;

....
p^.Free;
```

Then you can use `p^` to dereference the pointer and use the pointing object instance.

*A general advice about pointers: when working with pointers, it is good practice to not use generic `pointer` type (unless it is mandatory), but use strong types of pointers instead (like `p: ^TObject` or all the `P* = ^T*` types in most code): your code will be much easier to code and debugg.*

But be sure that your list store pointers on objects, not objects themselves.

Most of the time, a list store objects references themselves. In this case, just typecast `pointer` to `TObject`.

```
var L: TList;
    i: integer;

L := TList.Create;
try
  L.Add(TObject.Create); // create an instance and add to the list
  ...
finally
  for i := 0 to L.Count-1 do
    TObject(L[0]).Free; // typecast to TObject and free the instance
  L.Free; // free the list
end;
```

Of course, using a `TObjectList` here could be the natural way of doing it, but this shows a real use case of `pointer` <-> `TObject` typecast.